Error installing hplip downloaded from HP website
himanshu-singh@Apollo-B650M-GAMING-WIFI:~$ cd Desktop
himanshu-singh@Apollo-B650M-GAMING-WIFI:~/Desktop$ sh hplip-3.16.7.run
Creating directory hplip-3.16.7
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing HPLIP 3.16.7 Self Extracting Archive...........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
/home/himanshu-singh/Desktop/hplip-3.16.7/base/g.py:305: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\|'
  spinner = "\|/-\|/-"
/home/himanshu-singh/Desktop/hplip-3.16.7/base/g.py:355: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\d'
  m = re.search('python(\d(\.\d){0,2})', ext_path)            #get the python version where the .so file is found
/home/himanshu-singh/Desktop/hplip-3.16.7/base/logger.py:438: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\<'
  elem_start = re.findall("(\<\W{0,1}\w+) ?", line)[0]
/home/himanshu-singh/Desktop/hplip-3.16.7/base/logger.py:439: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\]'
  elem_finished = re.findall("([?|\]\]]*\>)", line)[0]
/home/himanshu-singh/Desktop/hplip-3.16.7/base/logger.py:441: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\S'
  attrs = re.findall("(\S*?\=\".*?\")", line)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/himanshu-singh/Desktop/hplip-3.16.7/./install.py", line 38, in <module>
    from base.g import *
  File "/home/himanshu-singh/Desktop/hplip-3.16.7/base/g.py", line 246, in <module>
    user_conf = UserConfig()
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/himanshu-singh/Desktop/hplip-3.16.7/base/g.py", line 213, in __init__
    ConfigBase.__init__(self, prop.user_config_file)
  File "/home/himanshu-singh/Desktop/hplip-3.16.7/base/g.py", line 90, in __init__
    self.read()
  File "/home/himanshu-singh/Desktop/hplip-3.16.7/base/g.py", line 131, in read
    self.conf.readfp(fp)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'ConfigParser' object has no attribute 'readfp'. Did you mean: 'read'?

How to fix this issue so that I can set up my printer?

You are trying to install a very old version (hplip-3.16.7) of hplip, released in July 2016. The current version is 3.24 (available on 24.04 repositories), and version 3.22 is available on the 22.04 repositories.
The hplip installer you are using uses the readfp attribute, which was deprecated in python3.2, and removed in python3.10, so it may not work in Ubuntu 22.04 or 24.04.

Solution 1.
Since hplip is available in the official Ubuntu repositories, just install it directly. Run the command
sudo apt install hplip


Solution 2.
This is not recommended because your installer is very old.
If you want to install the installer from HP instead of the one from Ubuntu's official repositories, then use read_file instead of readpf. Open the hplip-3.16.7.run file with a text editor, and replace the line self.conf.readfp(fp) with self.conf.read_file(fp), and it should work.
